# Get vertex positions in fragment shader

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, glsl, webgl

For certain reason, I need to get position of all vertices that form a primitive (triangle) in my fragment shader.

There are three ways I could do that: additional attributes, uniforms and via geometry shader.

**Attributes**:

```
// vertex shader
in vec3 vPosition;
in vec3 vposA;
in vec3 vposB;
in vec3 vposC;
out vec3 posA;
out vec3 posB;
out vec3 posC;

void main() {
    // ....
    posA = vposA;
    posB = vposB;
    posC = vposC;
}
```

Problems is that I need to send additional attributes, which means extra memory used in the VBOs.

**Uniforms**:

```
// fragment shader
uniform vec3 posA;
uniform vec3 posB;
uniform vec3 posC;

void main() {
    // ...
}
```

Main drawback is obviously need to bind uniforms for each triangle that is being drawn, so I can only draw one triangle per drawcall.

**GS**:

```
layout(triangles) in;
layout(triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;

out vec3 posA;
out vec3 posB;
out vec3 posC;

void main()
{
    posA = gl_in[0].gl_Position.xyz;
    posB = gl_in[1].gl_Position.xyz;
    posC = gl_in[2].gl_Position.xyz;

    gl_Position = gl_in[0].gl_Position;
    EmitVertex();
    gl_Position = gl_in[1].gl_Position;
    EmitVertex();
    gl_Position = gl_in[2].gl_Position;
    EmitVertex();
    EndPrimitive();
}
```

With GS I don't have need to store anything in memory, I can draw as many triangles I want, but problem is that entire new shader stage is being used.

I also considered using `flat` keyword, but that won't do here.

The question is, are there any other options, something that I may be missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geometry Shaders are the most practical approach, but that generally rules out WebGL.

You might consider taking a page from programmable vertex pulling, where your actual vertex data is stored in a buffer texture and you use an index to lookup the position values. I cannot comment on performance, but doing this would require ***significantly*** less storage per-vertex.

#### Here is a modified version of your original attribute-based attempt:

```
// vertex shader
in int vIdxA; // Index of vtx 0 in current triangle
in int vIdxB; // Index of vtx 1 in current triangle
in int vIdxC; // Index of vtx 2 in current triangle

out vec3 posA;
out vec3 posB;
out vec3 posC;

uniform samplerBuffer vtx_buf; // Actual vertex position array, as a buffer texture

void main() {
    int vtx = gl_VertexID % 3;

    // ....
    posA = texelFetch (vtx_buf, vIdxA);
    posB = texelFetch (vtx_buf, vIdxB);
    posC = texelFetch (vtx_buf, vIdxC);

    if (vtx == 0)
        gl_Position = posA;
    else if (vtx == 1)
        gl_Position = posB;
    else
        gl_Position = posC;
}
```

As implemented, this is also going to rule out WebGL, but it should be easier to adapt this approach to OpenGL ES than something based on a Geometry Shader.

Comment: It seems like you could use an attribute instead of using `gl_VertexID` and you can do the same in WebGL? [Here's a WebGL example putting vertex data in textures](http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/7t2Dj/).

Comment: @gman: I was not too concerned with that detail because `texelFetch` and buffer textures also will not work in WebGL without extensions. You'll have to normalize the texture coordinates and eliminate the integer vertex attributes. This was basically the simplest example I could come up with that does the work of a Geometry Shader (fetches and emits 3 vertices) on a per-vertex basis using the existing shader code as a base. My biggest concern was getting `posA`, `posB` and `posC` to be consistent for all vertices in the triangle so that varying interpolation did not mess things up.

Comment: It seemed to me that there might be some predefined variable that would maybe pass vertices' info to the fragment, because, during rasterization, each and every fragment is testing itself if it's contained inside of primitive, so it will get positions of the vertices anyway. Thanks for the idea @AndonM.Coleman.

Comment: @AbstractAlgorithm: You sort of have that backwards. During rasterization, a set of fragments that are covered by the primitive are generated. The only thing that you'll probably find per-fragment on modern hardware are the interpolated varyings and partial derivatives `dFdx` and `dFdy` (extension in WebGL), the fragment shader does not have to know the actual vertex positions. I do not know what you need to know the vertex positions for, but the partial derivative of interpolated coordinates can be just as useful sometimes; for example, you can compute a triangle's normal using it.

Comment: "Screen-space AABB" for the primitive is calculated and then those fragments are tested if contained inside the triangle, right? Not exactly fragment shader does need to know about vertices but that prior testing that is done before actual shader is run. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I think I'm missing your point. My point was both `gl_VertexID` and `texelFetch` and be worked around in WebGL. `gl_VertexID` with an attribute and `texelFetch` as in the example linked. Your vertices will need to be stored in a texture not a buffer but it should still be a solution. Did I miss something?

Comment: @gman: The point was, why muddy up a conceptual example with details required to make it work in WebGL? I could normalize the texture coordinates, remove the dependence on `gl_VertexID` and so forth, but it would require a heck of a lot more code to explain and there would be no benefit to doing so.

Comment: @AbstractAlgorithm: Correct, coverage is calculated before the fragment shader runs. But the data that generated it is not preserved. After rasterization, the only data left are your interpolated varyings :-\ Most of the time you only need the interpolated variable or the rate of change in the variable when working in the fragment shader.